# Moodle Docker Web Service working but can not be called from another docker container in the same network

Tags: docker, moodle, moodle-api

I am running a moodle docker container and one other container to call moodle web service function in a same network. I'm pretty sure I have set up the moodle properly because I can call moodle web service from postman. I am also aware i need to use the container alias of the running moodle container, which in this case is `webserver`. This is what i have tried

calling `http://localhost:8000/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json&wstoken=fa4e7222df472b032ca9b4bd6d17595a&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2` from Postman and it return the following response

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "admin",
            "firstname": "Admin",
            "lastname": "User",
            "fullname": "Admin User",
            "email": "abc@def.com",
            "department": "",
            "firstaccess": 1655901976,
            "lastaccess": 1655907821,
            "auth": "manual",
            "suspended": false,
            "confirmed": true,
            "lang": "en",
            "theme": "",
            "timezone": "99",
            "mailformat": 1,
            "description": "",
            "descriptionformat": 1,
            "profileimageurlsmall": "http://localhost:8000/theme/image.php/boost/core/1655902245/u/f2",
            "profileimageurl": "http://localhost:8000/theme/image.php/boost/core/1655902245/u/f1",
            "preferences": [
                {
                    "name": "core_message_migrate_data",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "auth_manual_passwordupdatetime",
                    "value": "1655902098"
                },
                {
                    "name": "email_bounce_count",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "email_send_count",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "login_failed_count_since_success",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_lastloaded",
                    "value": 1655907864
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "warnings": []
}
```

but when i try calling the same API from the other container i get a 403 response status, i also tried calling the same API with curl inside the container using `curl -v -g 'http://webserver/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=fa4e7222df472b032ca9b4bd6d17595a&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2'`

with result:

```
*   Trying 172.18.0.8:80...
* Connected to webserver (172.18.0.8) port 80 (#0)
> GET /webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=fa4e7222df472b032ca9b4bd6d17595a&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: webserver
> User-Agent: curl/7.80.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
< Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2022 14:42:38 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.29
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

so it is clearly connected but somehow still return 403 response, am i missing something? is there another moodle settings i have to tweak?

I am using [moodle-docker](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker) with added

```
networks:
  default:
    name: network_name
    external: true
```

at the end of `base.yml` file so it could connect to the current project I'm working on which is a Node.js project that will call one of the web service on moodle. Here is the `docker-compose.yml` which relevant to this question

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  test:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - "./.env"
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    networks:
      - network_name

networks:
  network_name:
    driver: bridge
    name: network_name
```

this is the result of calling docker logs of the moodle container

```
172.18.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2022:15:38:27 +0000] "GET /webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=fa4e7222df472b032ca9b4bd6d17595a&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1464 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"
[Wed Jun 22 15:38:30.315720 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 22] [client 172.18.0.3:34082] Debugging: The server died because the web services or the REST protocol are not enable in \n* line 39 of /webservice/rest/server.php: call to debugging()\n
172.18.0.3 - - [22/Jun/2022:15:38:30 +0000] "GET /webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=fa4e7222df472b032ca9b4bd6d17595a&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2 HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "-" "curl/7.80.0"
```

This error doesn't make any sense to me because i already enabled the web service and the REST protocol on the site administration settings. I also tried to enable web services for mobile devices with no luck so far. I'm also new to moodle development so I might miss something simple so any input is appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

After restarting the whole docker setup and try to curl from the container again I got this message:

```
*   Trying 172.19.0.8:80...
* Connected to webserver (172.19.0.8) port 80 ()
> GET /webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=beebce17854eff740ba85ec016542cfe&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: webserver
> User-Agent: curl/7.80.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2022 07:34:35 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.29
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 284
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
Install Behat before enabling it, use:
 php admin/tool/behat/cli/init.php
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/lib/testing/lib.php:169) in <b>/var/www/html/lib/testing/lib.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br />
* Connection #0 to host webserver left intact
```

After further investigation I found that in [config.docker-template.php](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker/blob/master/config.docker-template.php) there is a setting for `$CFG->behat_wwwroot` which has default value to `http://webserver`. I am not familiar how to setup testing framework in Moodle so I'm not sure how can I change this.

Now my problem is how to setup the moodle docker to both be exposed from `localhost` and `webserver`. Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Plesse add your Docker setup, how you created the Network and the Containers.

Comment: And the logs of your moodle container would help a lot

Comment: The second line in your logs look like you have to enable REST in your config

Comment: I already did, this is so weird because isn't postman using the same protocol? i only enable REST protocol and it works as expected using postman but not from inside the container somehow

Comment: Did you try to curl from your host?

Comment: i did try it just now and it works just fine

Comment: Can you please add the output of `docker network inspect network_name`, it shows all containers connected to your network

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

Since you have not mentioned the port cURL tries to connect to port `80` which is the default `http` port. You can observe it here:

```
* Connected to webserver (172.18.0.8) port 80 (#0)
```

#### Solution

You need to specifically set it as `8000`:

Instead of

```
'http://webserver/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=fa4e7222df472b032ca9b4bd6d17595a&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2'
```

It should be

```
'http://webserver:8000/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=fa4e7222df472b032ca9b4bd6d17595a&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=2'
```

Comment: the setup on [moodle-docker](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker) `base.yml` use bind mount on `/var/www/html` for the container so i think port 80 is the correct one, i tried curl to `http://webserver:8000` just now and i got error with this message `curl: (7) Failed to connect to webserver port 8000 after 1 ms: Connection refused`

Comment: your yaml has `version: "3.7"` can you and base.yml version: "2". I believe this is due some default network issue. can you try merging the services to a one file and try with your initial url?

Comment: that's a good point that i missed but sadly after i've tried it, it still didn't work

Answer (score -1):

you must use docker-compose to create  your network.

Comment: i did, i update the question which include my setup

Comment: This doesnt help to Solve the problem